# Отправка консольных команд программно

Tags: c#, cmd

использую данный код для отправки команды в командную строку:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();

        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir"); // Команда
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Однако, в качестве результата имею лишь открытую командную строку, без команды.

Comment: Странно, .NET Framework  4.5 и .NET Core 2.2 - полет нормальный. Никаких проблем нет.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам помогут [Directory.GetDirectories](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories) и [Directory.GetFiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles).
По поводу вашего вопроса. попробуйте так:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
{
    Arguments = "/C dir",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

Process cmd = Process.Start(psi);
cmd.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```